# Java - cannot bring the window to front

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                if (frame.getExtendedState() == Frame.ICONIFIED)
                                    frame.setExtendedState(Frame.NORMAL);
                                frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(!frame.getGlassPane().isVisible());

                                frame.toFront();
                                frame.repaint();

                            }
                        });
```

Unfortunately this does not bring it to the front from behind other windows...  Any solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the API documentation for `setExtendedState`:

> If the frame is currently visible on the screen (the
>   Window.isShowing() method returns true), **the developer should examine
>   the return value of the WindowEvent.getNewState() method of the
>   WindowEvent received through the WindowStateListener to determine that
>   the state has actually been changed**.
>
> If the frame is not visible on the screen, the events may or may not
>   be generated. In this case the developer may assume that the state
>   changes immediately after this method returns. Later, when the
>   setVisible(true) method is invoked, the frame will attempt to apply
>   this state. Receiving any WindowEvent.WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED events is
>   not guaranteed in this case also.

However, there is also a `windowDeiconified` callback you can hook into on `WindowListener`:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  private final WindowListener l = new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
      // Window now deiconified so bring it to the front.
      bringToFront();

      // Remove "one-shot" WindowListener to prevent memory leak.
      frame.removeWindowListener(this);
    }
  };

  public void run() {
    if (frame.getExtendedState() == Frame.ICONIFIED) {
      // Add listener and await callback once window has been deiconified.
      frame.addWindowListener(l);
      frame.setExtendedState(Frame.NORMAL);
    } else {
      // Bring to front synchronously.
      bringToFront();
    }
  }

  private void bringToFront() {
    frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(!frame.getGlassPane().isVisible());
    frame.toFront();
    // Note: Calling repaint explicitly should not be necessary.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that the following workaround for toFront() on a JDialog works on Windows 7 (haven't tested other platforms yet):

```
boolean aot = dialog.isAlwaysOnTop();
dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(aot);
```

Paul van Bemmelen